# Factorization of Matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Maybe this is obvious but I'm completely at a loss here. How do i write

$B = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{k}A_{11} & \mathbf{k}A_{12} \\ \mathbf{k}A_{21} & \mathbf{k}A_{22} \end{bmatrix}$

As a product of matrices/vectors where both $\mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{A_{ij}}$ is vectors.

Comment: is it elementwise multiplication? How do you multiply two vectors?

Comment: It's a dot product. Each element of B is just a number.

Comment: Then it is $diag(k,k)\cdot A$